# error: no matching function for call when compiled

Tags: c++

I am trying to write a simple C++ function using iterator for a vector as follows:

```
#include <iostream>
#include<vector>
#include<sstream>

using namespace std;
using vit = vector<string>::iterator;

void print(const vector<string>& s) {
  for(vit it = s.begin(); it != s.end(); ++it ){ 
    cout << *it << endl; 
  }
} 

int main() {
  std:: vector<int> v;
  for(int i = 0; i < v.size(); ++i)
    v[i] = 5 - i;
  print(v);
  return 0;
}
```

But I get a list of error including:

```
error: no matching function for call to print
```

I thought it might be because I used `iterator` instead of `const_iterator`, but the error persists after I fixed it. Why is that happening? Thanks!

Comment: `vector<string>` and `vector<int>` are different things.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`print()` only accepts an `std::vector<string>`. You're passing an `std::vector<int>` which is not the same thing.

If you want to be able to pass any `std::vector` you want, you'll need to create a template:

```
template <class type>
void print(const vector<type>& s) {
  for(auto it = s.begin(); it != s.end(); ++it ){ // vit is only for a std::vector<string>
    cout << *it << endl; 
  }
}
```

If you're attached to using `vit`, you could make that a template as well:

```
template <class type>
using vit = vector<type>::iterator;

template <class type>
void print(const vector<type>& s) {
  for(vit<type> it = s.begin(); it != s.end(); ++it ){ // vit now works with any type
    cout << *it << endl; 
  }
}
```

Comment: I agree with all of this, but personally I would just use `auto` for the declaration of the loop variable and not bother with `vit`.

Comment: Fair enough. I just figured I'd mention it because the OP seemed to want to use an iterator.

Comment: Like I said, I totally agree. If they're attached to using `vit` you've shown them how to do it. I just added a motivation to not be so attached to `vit`. And we know that the type deduced for `auto` will still be an `iterator`; we just save ourselves the trouble of figuring it out explicitly.

Comment: Thanks! But it still gives me an error of `Segmentation fault: 11` after I fixed the `const_iterator` and changed the int vector to string vector.

Comment: @KaihuaHou As a general rule, if you're experiencing another issue, then it's usually best to ask that in a separate question, containing your new code, including any changes you have made as a result of this one. Otherwise, it becomes very hard for us to help you debug your problem.

Comment: @KaihuaHou With that said, it's probably because you're not adding to your vector correctly. You should be using [push_back()](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/push_back), not the `v[i]` notation. That notation of expanding is usually for `std::map`s instead.

Comment: @Chipster Thanks so much!